# Dompdf multiple images in PDF

Tags: image, pdf, dompdf, generated

I'm rendering pure html to PDF using DOMPDF, but im having issue with multiple/dupicate image layers in generated PDF.

When i open generated PDF in Photoshop, there is option co see which images PDF have. In HTML im using only 2 images:

- 1st Defined as CSS background
- 2nd Defines with html `<\img>` tag

Image about this issue: [**https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA2EP.jpg**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA2EP.jpg)

Any ideas on this issue? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest version from git was solution to this issue.

See more at http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=447